# Androidのアプリ譲渡後のkeystoreの更新について

Tags: android

Androidアプリについて、以下のURLに従って、アプリ譲渡を行いました。
http://sitecatcher.net/blog/androidapp

アプリ譲渡自体はうまく行ったのですが、その後の（新しいアカウントでの）アプリのアップデートを行おうと思い、新しいバージョンのアプリのapkファイルをデベロッパーコンソールからアップロードしようとすると、keystoreが異なる旨のエラーが出て、アップロードできませんでした。
※keystoreは新しく譲渡先（当方）で作成したものです。

これはアプリ譲渡後もkeystore自体は元々のもの（アプリ譲渡元のkeystore）を使用するしかないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

元々のkeystoreを使用しないとダメです。

Answer (score 3):

アプリの譲渡は Google Play アカウント間の問題なので、アプリのパッケージ（apk）に対するデジタル署名の問題とは別々の話です。

アプリの譲渡とは無関係に、アプリのデジタル署名を変更することはできないので、アプリの譲渡をしたからといって変更が可能にならないのは当然です。

より詳細な話として、アプリはパッケージ名で識別されます。つまり、apkファイルというよりも、「パッケージ名」に対して「デジタル署名」が紐付けされるようなイメージです。

将来的に Google がこの紐付けを後から変更できるように仕様を変えない限り、現状では、変更不可能です。

このデジタル署名にあたって使われるのが、デジタル証明書ですね。

また、「デジタル証明書（certificate）」の話なので、「keystore」自体とは違います。keystore はデジタル証明書を保持しているデータベースのことです。従来の keystore から、該当するアプリの証明書をエクスポートして、新しい keystore にインポートすることが可能だと思います。操作方法等の詳細については、該当する情報を参照するなどしてください。
参考：[keytool ユーティリティーの使用](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/820-4604/6ng2cl1tv/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

既に回答されておりますが、一応公式ドキュメントより引用。

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)より

> You should sign all of your apps with the same certificate throughout the expected lifespan of your applications.

アプリケーションは同じ証明書を使い続ける必要があります。たとえば`keystore`を紛失した場合、二度とアップデートできません。

> If you sign the new version with a different certificate, you must assign a different package name to the application—in this case, the user installs the new version as a completely new application.

もし異なる証明書で署名した新しいバージョンを公開するのであれば、異なるパッケージ名を付けて、完全に別のアプリケーションとして公開する必要があります。